# Attemp to call a nil value (field ‘ShowInventory’) [ESX2]

Tags: lua, inventory, esx, fivem

I just installed ESX 2 into my new server, im Really new at lua and i dont really know what i should do with some resources or how to start coding

I wan to work in the inventory system based on es_extended, but, it doesnt work.

I press the Inventory Key informed in the cofig file \server-data\resources\es_extended\config\default\config.lua

“Config.InventoryKey = “REPLAY_START_STOP_RECORDING_SECONDARY” – Key F2 by default”

```
module.InitESX = function()
  module.RegisterControl(module.Groups.MOVE, module.Controls[Config.InventoryKey])
  module.On('released', module.Groups.MOVE, module.Controls[Config.InventoryKey], function(lastPressed)
    print("Comment before show The Inventory")
    ESX.ShowInventory()
    -- if Menu.IsOpen ~= nil then
        --  if (not ESX.IsDead) and (not Menu.IsOpen('default', 'es_extended', 'inventory')) then
        --    ESX.ShowInventory()
        --  end 
        -- end
  end)
end
```

I literally change a little bit the code to directly execute the ShowInventory() Function but i got this error

[image]

the original code look like this

```
module.InitESX = function()
  module.RegisterControl(module.Groups.MOVE, module.Controls[Config.InventoryKey])
  module.On('released', module.Groups.MOVE, module.Controls[Config.InventoryKey], function(lastPressed)
    if Menu.IsOpen ~= nil then
            if (not ESX.IsDead) and (not Menu.IsOpen('default', 'es_extended', 'inventory')) then
              ESX.ShowInventory()
            end 
        end
  end)
end
```

but when i press the key dont do nothing and doesnt show anything in the console.

Comment: well you're calling a nil value. ESX.ShowInventory does not exist in that scope. Maybe there is a reason why it was in that conditional block? did it work befor you moved it out of that block?   sharing screenshots of code is nonsense btw. please copy and paste the code. At least crop the screenshot.

Comment: Im sorry for not to put the crop of the code instead of a screenshot, i look around ALL the files where it can be the functionality of ShowInventory() to read what it do but it is not declared anywhere but theres a looot of places where it get used.

I'm starting with lua, I have a noticeable lack of understanding, so I apologize if I'm making a big and glaring mistake.

Comment: it's just that calling nil values doesn't make sense. Lua doesn't know what to do here. For some reson `ESX.ShowInventory()` does not exist where you're trying to call it. hence the question if it worked befor you changed those things

Comment: I know, I understand that there should be a ShowInventory function somewhere ESX.
I understand that the instruction should be read.
From the ESX library use the ShowInventory () method or function

This has never worked, since I installed it 4 days ago I have been suffering, reading and investigating if this function exists or should I write it. And if I have to write it, where should I put it?

Because there is a module called Inventory where it seems to be the functionality that the ShowInventory method should invoke but I can't make it work.